# mysql limit sub query

Tags: mysql, subquery, limit

I wanna set the limit in my sql query dynamically. I would like to set the limit in a parameter table.

```
select col1, col2, col3 
from table 
where col4 = 'abc' 
limit (select a from param)
```

How to achieve this? Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PREPARED STATEMENTS`

```
mysql> select * from t;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
+----+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> prepare stmt from 'select * from t limit ?';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Statement prepared

mysql> set @v = 2;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> execute stmt using @v;
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> deallocate prepare stmt;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use parameters for `limit` (unless you have a prepared statement).  You can use variables to enumerate the rows:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from (select t.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as rn
      from table cross join
           (select @rn := 0) const
     ) t
where rn <= PARAMETERVALUE;
```

Although I used a subquery for this, I think you can also do:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from table t cross join
     (select @rn := 0) const
where (@rn := @rn + 1) <= PARAMETERVALUE;
```